# Einstein chatbot dialog translation

Tags: einstein-bots

I am aware that the following issue currently exists: Standard bots with multi-language enabled are seeing system dialogs in the footer menu not translated. I would like to understand if the same issue exists for Enhanced bots as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Translated bot options menu is not supported for Enhanced bots. However there is an work item (W-12234009) internally that is been worked upon with no ETA on when this feature will be available.